# ffmpeg macos hardware acceleration: use more GPU

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, hardware-acceleration

I am trying to use ffmpeg to convert some videos to MP4.

I have a Mac, and am using h464_videotoolbox to use hardware acceleration.

`ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel fatal -stats -i in.ts -vcodec h264_videotoolbox -b:v 3000k -acodec aac out.mp4`

This works, but I have noticed that ffmpeg is not using nearly a majority of GPU processing power, and it seems to prefer the integrated GPU vs using the discrete GPU.

Is there a way to force FFMPEG to use a specified GPU? Also, is there a way to tell FFMPEG "hey you can use x% of GPU" to allow it to use more GPU to have encodes take less time?

From Activity Monitor, it looks like its not nearly using all processing power of integrated, and barely (if at all) using discrete:
[graph from activity monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vw1Qr.png)

Thanks! Any input is extremely appreciated :)

Computer details:
Model Name:   MacBook Pro
Model Identifier: MacBookPro16,1
Processor Name:   6-Core Intel Core i7
Processor Speed:  2.6 GHz
Number of Processors: 1
Total Number of Cores:    6

Discrete Graphics: AMD Radeon Pro 5500M
Integrated Graphics: Intel UHD Graphics 630